# How to edit a snippet once inserted in the Stack Overflow answer?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I am having a very simple problem, that is, when I insert a snippet for an answer then how do I again open it in the editor and edit it?

Whenever I click the snippet button to edit, then I get everything blank and I again have to copy the code from my own answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a link, "**edit the above snippet**" under the "Run code snippet" button when you edit your post.

[image: Edit snippet]

Comment: Note: you have to press "Show preview" to render the snippet view, and then the edit options becomes available. I found this not to be very obvious because I mostly work from the raw editor.

Comment: I am happy that there are at least 15 other people who did not find the link on their own. Maybe this link should be highlighted somehow.

Comment: Yep - I can't believe they still haven't made it more apparent that it exists